# Play Audio (mp3) from Rails Controller via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

We are wanting to generate an audio file from an ajax call, return the data from that file and have Javascript play the audio on a page.
But we are getting

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

```
# in the controller
def preview
    file_name = Tempfile.new(["preview", '.mp3'], binmode: true)
  # fill file with data here

# after writing out file

    Rails.logger.debug Mp3Info.open(file_name.path)
    soundfile = File.open(file_name.path, 'r')
    binary = soundfile.read
  
    send_data binary, filename: 'preview.mp3', type: 'audio/mp3', disposition: 'inline'
end
```

On the page

```
<form id='test-gallery'>
<%= text_field_tag 'input-field-thing' %>
</form>

<script>
        $( "#control-thing" ).on( "click", function() {       
          var identifyingStuff = $("#input-field-thing").val();
          console.log(identifyingStuff);

          Rails.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/sound_gallery/preview.js",
            data: Rails.serializeElement(Rails.$("form")[0]),
            success: (response) => {
              console.log(response);

              var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'audio/mp3' });
              console.log(blob);

              var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); //where value is the blob
              console.log(url);
              var audio = new Audio();
              audio.src = url;
              audio.play();
            },
          });
        });
</script>
```

The `console.log(response)` on the front end writes out what appears to be a binary file. Looking like this (I had to use an image because the paste in cause SO to not save!):

[image: console.log(response)]

and the `console.log(blob)` writes this

```
Blob {size: 17989, type: "audio/mpeg"}
```

We leads me to believe that the data is getting sent properly, but really at this point I have no idea.

The 'Network' panel of the browser shows a `Status: 206` for the blob when it is played. That will be the source of the browser error, but the question remains 'why?'.

Comment: What are your network tools showing the response as?

Comment: That controller code makes no sense at all. In the first line you are creating a Tempfile and then you in an very convoluted way read its contents which is empty since you never wrote anything to the file. A tempfile is actually a fully fledged IO object and yet you're treating it like its just some kind of file path. If you actually want to do something meaningful with the file do `file = Tempfile.new(["preview", '.mp3'], binmode: true);  file.write(some_data); file.rewind; binary = file.read`. https://remimercier.com/working-with-tempfiles/

Comment: I left out the part where we write to the file as it is not relevant. Sorry, the code comment was meant to indicate that

Comment: @JoshBrody - I added some debug output from the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and leaving this here in case I can save anyone else days of work.

I did not need to change anything on the server side. The `send_data` works fine.

On the front end, I could not get this to work using `Rails.ajax`.
Below is a solution that works using `XMLHttpRequest`

```
<form id='test-gallery'>
<%= text_field_tag 'input-field-thing' %>
</form>
<span id='control-thing1'>XMLHttpRequest</span>

<script>
        $( "#control-thing1" ).on( "click", function(e) {
          let token = document.getElementsByName("csrf-token")[0].content;
          e.preventDefault();
          let inputText = $('#input-field-thing').val();
          let data = JSON.stringify({'input': inputText});

          let xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
          xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "/sound_gallery/preview.js");
          xmlHttpRequest.responseType = "blob"; // <-- this is what can't be set in Rails.ajax
          xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
          xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token); 
          xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
              var audio = new Audio();
              audio.src = url;
              audio.play();
            }
          };

          xmlHttpRequest.send(data); 

       });

</script>
```